# How to Handle Method Overriding for Two Interfaces with the Same Methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have two separate `interfaces`, `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`, both containing a method named `commonMethod(...)` with different parameter types. Now, I need to implement a class `MyClass` that should override both interfaces `commonMethod(...)` with different behaviors based on the context.

Here's a simplified representation of the code:

```dart
abstract class InterfaceA {
  void commonMethod(int parameter);
}

abstract class InterfaceB {
  void commonMethod(String parameter);
}

class MyClass implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
  // How can I override the commonMethod for both InterfaceA and InterfaceB?
}
```

I'm looking for a solution or workaround that will allow me to `override` the `commonMethod` for both interfaces.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a method which is compatible with both interfaces. In your case, the common type between `int` and `String` is `Object`. So we need a method like:

```dart
abstract class InterfaceA {
  void commonMethod(int value);
}

abstract class InterfaceB {
  void commonMethod(String value);
}

class MyClass implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
  @override
  void commonMethod(Object input) {
    if (input is int) {
      print('We got int');
    } else if (input is String) {
      print('We got String');
    } else {
      print('Unexpected type. Should not happen!');
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  InterfaceA a = MyClass();
  InterfaceB b = MyClass();

  a.commonMethod(5);       // We got int
  b.commonMethod('test');  // We got String
}
```

You can then in the method check what type of object you got and add logic that fits that more specific type.

Comment: Thanks @julemand101 for your answare, but it doesn't work for my case. I have updated my question.

Comment: @Hamed Updated answer to fit the new version of the question.

Comment: This is OK, but it is open to modification. I wonder is there any way to maintain Open-Closed Principle?